# Django multiple authentication backend superuser location

Tags: django, authentication

I am using django. Besides django.contrib.auth I have made a second authentication backend django.contrib.companyauth and similar folder of corresponding contenttypes in django.contrib . Everything works fine, but when I run syncdb, the superuser is created in companyauth>Users (i.e. in users table of 2nd authentication backend) of admin page, instead I need this superuser to be created in auth>Users of admin page. How to achieve this ? (I am not able to find out any temporary way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your company user must "extend" from Auth.User if you want to use any Django authorization tools...

Try to change your company user model to something like this

```
class CompanyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ## Whatever fields you want to use 
    observations= models.CharField(max_length=2048)
```

This way, your request.user is a Auth.User and if you want to get the company user you just need to:

```
CompanyUser.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Honestly, I wouldn't implement another authorization system...

Now to answer your question, here's how you create a user, in this case, a super user:

```
## Creating Auth.User
base_user = User.objects.create(
    username  = 'username', 
    password  = make_password('password') , 
    email     = 'email',
    first_name= 'first_name',
    last_name = 'last_name',
    is_superuser = 1
)
## Extending User to CompanyUser
extended_user = CompanyUser.objects.create(
    user = base_user, 
    observations='observations'
)
```

I hope it helps ;-)

Comment: That helps. Although I have already implemented another authorization system with the help of in built auth, but I'll surely use this in my future projects.

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful.